# Cat file that filename are in a file

Tags: bash, cat

I have a file where I have lot of file name:

```
file1.txt
file2.txt
file3.txt
file4.txt
...
fileN.txt
```

I want to cat all the file that are present in this file

Answer (score 1):

Since you tagged [bash](/questions/tagged/bash):

```
cat $(< file)
```

Comment: Break on file names with spaces or newlines or anything from the `$IFS` environment. Work only with Zsh and Bash.